# How do I get the color of a color-picker on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background:**

I am trying to get the current value of a color picker when I click my `onSubmit` button. The color picker is in a separate component.

**Problem:**

When I change the color via the color picker, I am getting an error message that says: `TypeError: _this.props.setSelectedColor is not a function`

**Component that has Color Picker Inside of It:**

```
function myFunctionA(props) {

  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState(null)

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(selectedColor);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <MyColorPicker setSelectedColor/>
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Color Picker Code:**

```
class MyBlockPicker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    background: this.props.background,
  };

  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    console.log(color);
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
    this.props.setSelectedColor(color.hex)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BlockPicker
        color={this.state.background}
        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyBlockPicker;
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a function down to a child you need to do it like this:

```
<MyColorPicker setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor} />
```

Comment: This. @Brandon your current syntax evaluates to `setSelectedColor={true}`. If you don't pass a specific value for a property you define, it's implied to be `true`.

Comment: One related question, how do I pre-populate the background color from the parent component?

Comment: You could i.e. initialize your state in the first place: `const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("your color here")`